# Schengen visa duration: when does the clock start ticking?

Tags: visas, schengen

I am from Vietnam and my Schengen visa duration is 5 days. My flight itinerary is as follow:

3/11: 19:00 - 21:15 : Hanoi - Saigon.

3/11-4/11: 23:05 - 6:55 : Saigon - Paris.

4/11: 10:05 - 11:15 : Paris - Switzerland.

My question is that when does my duration start counting. Is it 3/11 when I leave Hanoi or 4/11 when I arrive at Paris (23:05 is my local time in Vietnam and 6:55 is Paris local time). Does the time start when I've arrived in Paris or when I start at Saigon?

I need the correct time so I can plan my departure.

Comment: You will enter the Schengen Area in Paris, where you will recieve an **entry** stamp. The date of the entry stamp is what the Border Guards, when leaving, will use to calculate the duration of your stay.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Schengen visa clock starts ticking when you physically arrive in Paris and pass through Immigration at the Paris airport. The [Schengen Borders Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02016R0399-20170407) says this at Article 6(2):

> ...the date of entry shall be considered as the first day of stay on the territory of the Member States and the date of exit shall be considered as the last day of stay on the territory of the Member States...

The entry date must be on, or after, the first "validity date" as shown on your Schengen "C" visa. You must leave the Schengen area on or before the "valid until" date as shown on the visa.

Comment: It’s worth noting that Schengen days are calendar days. If you enter on the 4th at 7am, the full day is counted, so 5 days end on the 8th at midnight (in the night from 8th to 9th),  not on the 9th at 7am.

Comment: The date shown on the **entry** stamp is what counts.